# Different languages in sitemap

Tags: xml, sitemap

I have two different languages on the same domain like this:

```
www.mydomain.com/about (english)
www.mydomain.com/se/om (swedish)
```

Would it be ok to list all pages in the same sitemap (www.mydomain.com/sitemap.xml)?

Comment: Whom or what are you worried about offending?  The sitemap police?  If your sitemap.xml document is intended for human readers, I should think having all your pages listed would be a plus.  If you intend it for automatic processing of some kind, it's those responsible for that automatic processing you need to be asking, not Stack Overflow.  Good luck.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question: Would search engines like Google, Bing and Yahoo want me to have two different sitemaps or would it be okay to mix different languages pages in the same sitemap?